# Can I mock a rest call within a java method

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have 2 methods, I want to call the first public method, which in turn will call a private method, in the private method I want to make a call to an external service and mock a 500 internal service error from the GET request in there. I know how to mock the whole private method but that won't work I want to see what happens in there specifically when i get a 500 back from the external service.

Here is what the 2 methods i am testing look like..

```
@Resource(name = "serviceRestTemplate")
private OAuth2RestTemplate serviceRestTemplate;

public ResponseEntity<Cargo> getById(String id) throws MyException {

    UriComponentsBuilder newUri = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromHttpUrl(url + id + HEADER_URI);
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = this.callNewService(newUri, HttpMethod.GET);
    // more irrelivent code...
}

private ResponseEntity<String> callNewService(UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder, HttpMethod method) throws MyException {

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;
    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        responseEntity = serviceRestTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(),
                method, requestEntity, String.class);

    }catch(HttpClientErrorException httpClientErrorException) {
        LOGGER.error("Error when calling Service. {} ", uriBuilder.toUriString());
        LOGGER.error("Error message from HttpClientErrorException . {} ", httpClientErrorException.getMessage());
        throw buildException(httpClientErrorException.getMessage(), httpClientErrorException.getRawStatusCode());
    }

    if(null != responseEntity
            && responseEntity.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()
            && EDMRESTServiceUtilities.isJsonValid(responseEntity.getBody())) {
        LOGGER.info("Service response: {}", responseEntity.getBody());
        return responseEntity;
    }else {
        LOGGER.error("Error response from Service. {} ", uriBuilder.toUriString());
        throw buildException(SERVICE_ERROR_MESSAGE, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
    }
}
```

Comment: mock the serviceRestTemplate

Comment: You could use `TestRestTempate` or you could use something like OkHttp or Java Spark to create a mock service for the rest template to connect too.  Given RestTemplate isint an interface or a class that you "own" I dont thinking mocking it is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock your `serviceRestTemplate` and the call to `exchange` in the tests and change your method of injection to Constructor injection it will make it easier to use the mock in your class.